# How does loss.backward() relate to the appropriate parameters of the model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new in PyTorch and I'm having trouble understanding how `loss` knows to compute the gradients through `loss.backward()`?

Sure, I understand that the parameters need to have `requires_grad=True` and I understand that it sets `x.grad` to the appropriate gradient only for the optimizer later to perform the gradient update.

The optimizer is linked to the model parameters when it's instantiated, but the loss is never linked to the model.

I've been going through [this thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-are-optimizer-step-and-loss-backward-related/7350/3), but I don't think anyone answered it clearly and the person that started the thread seems to have the same issue as I do.

What happens when I have two different networks with two different loss functions and two different optimizers. I will easily link the optimizers to each of the networks, but how will the loss functions know how to compute the gradients for each of their appropriate network if I never link them together?

Comment: This is a good question. From what I understand, and I haven't found clear documentation stating this, but `loss.backward()` calculates the gradients of ANY network as long as `requires_grad=True`. If you're dealing with a single network this is fine, but when you're working with multiple networks, such as with GANs, this gets a little weird.
As @zafirzarya stated, the optimizer is linked to the model parameters so it would make sense that `loss.backward()` is but as far as I can tell it's a global operation.

Answer (score 3):

Loss is itself a tensor which is derived from the parameters of the network. A graph is implicitly constructed where each new tensor, including loss, points back to the tensors which were involved with it's construction. When you apply `loss.backward()` pytorch follows the graph backwards and populates the `.grad` member of each tensor with the partial dervative of loss with respect to that tensor using the chain rule (i.e. backpropagation)

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to be very general so I can only provide suggestions to get you started (I hope):

- Plot the graph to understand how data flows in your computation graph
- Look at torch.autograd documentation to see how the framework records all operations that it will use for computing gradients ("backward") https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html
- You can use hooks (available with Python 3 + PyTorch) to figure out the gradient values. It should also give you a sense for how gradients are flowing in your graph
  Could you please post graphs of the graph(s) so that you can get concrete answers?

If the above does not answer your question, I ask that you clarify your question with example code

Comment: Which graph can be ploted? or how?

Comment: The graph mentioned above refers to the computation graph that PyTorch constructs to run forward and backward. 
Latest version of PyTorch has Tensorboard integration that you can use to plot the graph (add_graph). See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html for API and example usage